# jQuery validate Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null

Tags: validation, jquery-validate

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready
(
    function ()
    {
        $.validator.addMethod(
        "lessThan",
        function (value, element, param)
        {
            // bind to the blur event of the target in order to revalidate whenever the target field is updated            
            var target = $(param)
            .unbind(".validate-lessThan")
            .bind
            (
                "blur.validate-lessThan",
                function ()
                {
                    $(element).valid();
                }
            );
            return parseFloat(value) <= parseFloat(target.val());
        },
        "Valoarea trebuie sa fie mai mica sau egala decat valoarea initiala"
        );
    }
);


$('#gvListDetaliiElemTranAdaugare input[name$=Valoare]').each
    (
        function (index, domEle)
        {
            $(this).rules
            (
                "add"
                , {

                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    range: [0.1, Number.MAX_VALUE],
                    lessThan: '#ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_' + index + '__ValoareRamasa',
                    messages:
                    {
                        required: "Valoarea este necesara!",
                        minlength: "Valoarea este necesara!",
                        range: "Valoarea este necesara!",
                        lessThan: "Valoarea trebuie sa fie mai mica sau egala cu " + $('#ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_' + index + '__ValoareRamasa').val()


                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

The code fails then it reeaches $(this).rules() with: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`.
 the html returned by `$('#gvListDetaliiElemTranAdaugare input[name$=Valoare]')` is:

```
[
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_0__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[0]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 18590 , 0)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_1__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[1]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 22972 , 1)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_2__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[2]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 23036 , 2)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_3__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[3]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 23038 , 3)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_4__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[4]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 425306 , 4)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_5__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[5]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 425308 , 5)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_6__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[6]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 425309 , 6)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
, 
<input data-type=​"decimal" id=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare_7__Valoare" name=​"ListaDetaliiElemTranModelAdaugare[7]​.Valoare" onchange=​"OnValoareChange($(this)​.val()​, 425310 , 7)​" type=​"text" value=​"0.00000000000">​
]
```

Comment: why you are not just adding the validate function with its rules as properties in json ?

Comment: check this page http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: I didn;t find anything useful there

Comment: what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to add validation to a set of grid rows. But i have found my problem. Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The problem was that the HTML I was trying to validate was not contained within a `<form>...</form>` tag.

As soon as I did that, I had a **`context`** that was not null.

Comment: This one caught me for almost 2 hours... the element must be inside a form. Duhhhh :( Thanks for sharing! :) Just to mention: in my case I was trying to add a rule to an input file. This is the so helpful error I got on Firebug: `elem null` on this jQuery line: `f ( elem.nodeType && elem.nodeType !== 1 && elem.nodeType !== 9 )`

Comment: It made me like an idiot in the past hour, fields were all in a form but when jQuery dialog opened, it moved them out of the form, then validation failed with a strange error message. Why jQuery UI doesn't issue a warning message in the console?

Answer (score 5):

The problem happened because I was trying to bind a HTML element before it was created.

My script was loaded on top of the HTML and it needs to be loaded at the bottom of my HTML code.

Comment: same case for me,
I was also adding rules on the nested form before insert event. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in a Backbone project: my view contains a input and is re-rendered. 
Here is what happens (example for a checkbox):

- The first render occurs;
- jquery.validate is applied, adding an event onClick on the input;
- View re-renders, the original input disappears but jquery.validate is still bound to it.

The solution is to update the input rather than re-render it completely. Here is an idea of the implementation:

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        if(this.rendered){
            this.update();
            return;
        }
        this.rendered = true;

        this.$el.html(tpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    update: function(){
        this.$el.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.model.get('checked'));
        return this;
    }
});
```

This way you don't have to change any existing code calling render(), simply make sure update() keeps your HTML in sync and you're good to go.

Comment: I don't understand this, could you tell me how to apply it in practice?

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer when I was getting a similar error for `nodeName` after upgrading to Bootstrap 4. The issue was that the tabs didn't have the `nav` and `nav-tab` classes; adding those to the `<ul>` element fixed the issue.

Comment: Wow... took some time to realize this. This also works without `<ul>`, so applying `class="nav nav-tabs"` to a parent element is enough. But is definitely a Bootstrap 4 issue. Bootstrap 3 was fine without.

Answer (score 1):

Extract from the oficial docs:

***Requires that the parent form is validated, that is, $( "form" ).validate() is called first***

more about... [rules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when the number of `<th>` tags in the '' did not match the number of  in the `<tfoot>` section

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Subject Areas</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option(s)</th>
    <tr>
</thead>

<tbody></tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because the panel was outside of the [data-role="page"] element.